# Is it a good design with all-in-one tables?

Tags: database

I have a social networking system, and there are topics, tasks, questions, links, documents, videos and so on. I plan to put all of them to one table named `posts`, and there is one column name `kind` to identify. Is it a good design ? why ?

BTW:

1、I am using postgresql 
2、I just think there are many repeated columns between them , for example: the title, the content, the created_at and the author

Answer (score 2):

From your description it seems like all these domain objects have something in common. Otherwise you wouldn't even think about storing them in one table. Accidently or not what you have described is one of the techniques of mapping inheritance to relational model, called [*single table*](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html#MapHierarchyToTable). The link above describes in detail other techniques and what are their [pros and cons](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html#ComparingTheStrategies).

Answer (score 1):

You can't index columns for which you want to perform search on it. Why do you want to put everything in the same table at the first place?

Comment: I just think there are many repeated columns between them ,  for example: the title, the content, the created_at and the author

Comment: if you are using Postgresql you can use table inheritance: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/ddl-inherit.html

Answer (score 0):

No. It limits these things to all having the same attributes.  So if, for example, a "Link" needed a URL field, a topic, a task, a question, etc would all have to have one too.

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT a good design with postgresql. [Normalizing data](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/performance/sql-by-design-why-you-need-database-normalization) in a relational database is very important.

You should consider using a NoSQL database system such as [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/).

Comment: Is it a good design with any DB?